# How can I minimize the following function

Tags: functions, numerical-methods

I have a simple function and want to minimize it using any method with precision of about 0.01. The domain of x is [-2,2]. The function is a simple $f(x) = x^2$ plus a triangle in the form of $-(abs(x-z1)/0.1+1), \forall x\in[z1-0.1,z1+0.1]$, where z1 is a predefined and fixed value. A sample illustration is shown below for z1=0.1 (red ^) which is added to $x^2$. Please note that the function is not derivative in $z1$. Any analytic or numeric method is appreciated, but more efficient method is preferred in terms of required time and convergence to the real minimum.

[image]

Comment: Your function is still wrong. The correct g function for your triangle is: $g:x\mapsto 1−\frac{|x−z_1|}{0.1}$. The one you've written is always negative so it cannot be the one you plotted. Moreover your plot is for $z_1=1.1$ and not $0.1$ ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make any mistake on your triangle's form ? ($\frac{|x−z_1|}{0.1}+1$)

Because if not, then your graph is wrong. You say it is plotted for $z_1=0.1$ but then the bounds of your triangle on the $x$ axis should be $z_1−0.1=0$ and $z_1+0.1=0.2$. and your triangle would be upside down (look at how the $x↦|x|$ looks like). Your plot should actually look like this:

[image: plot]

If however there is a mistake in your function but the plot is correct then you have your answer below:

Since your function is of the form $h=f+g$ where $g$ is your triangle, and since $g\geq 0$ then $h\geq f$ and so the minimum of $h$ is greater or equal to the minimum of $f$:

$\displaystyle\inf_{[-2,2]}(f+g)=\inf_{[-2,2]}(x^2+g)\geq\inf_{[-2,2]}(x^2)$

Now you have the equality when your triangle does not "overlap" the $x=0$ point ($f$'s minimum). If it does, then your minimum is the minimum of $(z_1-0.1)^2$ and $(z_1+0.1)^2$:

$\displaystyle\inf_{[-2,2]}(f+g) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \mbox{if} & 0\notin [z_1-0.1,z_1+0.1] \\ min((z_1-0.1)^2,(z_1+0.1)^2) & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right)$

Ok so now you let's assume that you have $n\in\Bbb{N}$ similar triangles. Each of those triangles is represented by a function $g_i$ centered on $z_i$:

$\displaystyle\forall i\in[1,n],\cases{z_i\in[-1.9,1.9] \\ \space g_i:x\mapsto 1-\frac{|x-z_i|}{0.1}}$

Your total function is called $h$:

$h=\displaystyle f+\sum_{i=1}^n g_i$ where $f:x\mapsto x^2$

Each function $g_i$ is defined on the interval $\displaystyle I_i=[z_i-0.1,z_i+0.1]=[l_i,u_i]$. Let us denote the union of all those intervals by $\displaystyle I=\bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i$

Now in the same way as for the "one triangle" case, you have:

$\displaystyle\inf_{[-2,2]}(h) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \mbox{if} & 0\notin I \\ min_{i\in[1,n]}(l_i^2,u_i^2) & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right)$

The two cases are illustrated here under:

Case 1: $0\in I$:

The minimum of the function (indicated with the red arrow) is the minimum of the two red points (the bounds of $I_1\bigcup I_2$ the resulting union of intervals surrounding $0$)
[image: Plot with 0]

Case 2: $0\notin I$:

Here, the minimum is $0$ and is the minimum of all the red points plus $0$ (the bounds of each distinct interval resulting from the union $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i$) Here you have three distinct intervals in the union: $I_1\bigcup I_2$, $I_3$ and $I_4\bigcup I_5$
[image: Plot without 0]

Comment: Thank you really for your comment and sorry for the mistake in the formula (I corrected it and the plot is correct). If I have multiple such triangles, if your answer can be extended?

Comment: Just edited my answer to add the multiple triangles case ;)

Comment: Thank you again. As you said, I think it is sufficient to check only $(z_i-0.1)$, $(z_i+0.1)$, and if two triangles overlap (/v\), we must check the overlap point! Correct?

Comment: I've added some pictures in my post to show you what happens

Comment: Thank you for your help and figures. So, I must find distinct intervals and calculate the function around them along with y=f(x=0) and choose the min. Thank you again.